# Footer is not showing on bottom in listview

Tags: android, listview, footer

I want to add a view  at the bottom of listview as a footer but its coming at the top.I have tried so many approaches but all in vain.

This is my xml....which contains listview and includes footer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EFEFEF"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDeleteUserInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/manage_product_frag_delete" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnDeleteUserInfo"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvUserInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewHorizontal"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lvUserInfo"
        layout="@layout/administration_add_user_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is code:

```
 lvUserInfo = (ListView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.lvUserInfo);
    userInfoAdapter = new AdministrationUserInfoAdapter(getActivity());
    lvUserInfo.setAdapter(userInfoAdapter);
    userInfoAdapter.addData(fillDataset());
    View footer=(View) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.footer);
    lvUserInfo.addFooterView(footer, null,true);
```

Please help ..i really can't find out where I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EFEFEF"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDeleteUserInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/manage_product_frag_delete" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <ListView
       android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/lvUserInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>

    <include
        layout="@layout/administration_add_user_view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#EFEFEF"
android:padding="15dp" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnDeleteUserInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:src="@drawable/manage_product_frag_delete" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/tab_layout" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnDeleteUserInfo"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#000000" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvUserInfo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/viewHorizontal"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
 </ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust relative views.try this one,it will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EFEFEF"
    android:padding="15dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    >    

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDeleteUserInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/manage_product_frag_delete" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnDeleteUserInfo"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvUserInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewHorizontal"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>    

   <include
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/administration_add_user_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope it will be helpful !!